# I want to extract the value from JSON by same id one id using java

Tags: java, json, json-arrayagg

So the json look like this

```
{
"cover":"AddressBook",
"Addresses":[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "NickName":"Rahul",
        "ContactName":"Dravid",
        "Company":"Cricket",
        "City":"Indore",
        "Country":"India",
        "Type":"Address"
     },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "NickName":"Sachin",
        "ContactName":"Tendulkar",
        "Company":"Cricket",
        "City":"Mumbai",
        "Country":"India",
        "Type":"Address"
     }
]
```

}

I want to extract the data from the id = 1 using the JSON array, but I am not sure how to use the syntax or some other way the code I have is this :

```
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("AddressBook.json");
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
        address = (JSONArray)obj;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through the "Addresses" array.

```
JSONObject addressBook = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
JSONArray addresses = (JSONArray) addressBook.get("Addresses");
JSONObject address = null;
for (Object find : addresses) {
    if (((JSONObject) find).get("id").equals("1")) {
        address = (JSONObject) find;
    }
}
System.out.println(address.toJSONString());
```

Output

```
{"Company":"Cricket","Type":"Address","Country":"India","id":"1","City":"Indore","NickName":"Rahul","ContactName":"Dravid"}
```

Comment: so if I just want the country type what I should do is that JSONObject jsonName = (JSONObject) o; String name = (String)jsonName.get("Country");?

Comment: Continue my coding above where JSONObject address is defined...  String name = (String) address.get("Country");

Comment: So if I want to get the city is this look good ?                                                          
     public String getCity(int id) {
            JSONObject add = null;
        for(Object find : address){
            if(((JSONObject)find).get("id").equals(id)){
                add = (JSONObject) find;
            }
        }
        city = (String)add.get("City");
        return city;
    
    }

Comment: Good, and practice more.  Enjoy programming!